# For every natural number n, prove that the vector $x = (n, n + 1, n (n + 1)) ∈ \Bbb R^3$ has as a norm a natural number, that is, $\|x\| \in \Bbb N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

> For every natural number $n$, prove that the vector $x = (n, n + 1, n (n + 1))$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}^3$ has as a norm a natural number, that is, $\|x\| \in \mathbb{N}$.

I made the internal product of the vector $x$ which gave $n^4 + 3n^3 + n^2$. Now I can't prove by induction. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Check again. I have that $\|x\|= \sqrt{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can go about it.  You can assume that the expression inside the radial is a perfect square.  Then, $n^4+2n^3+3n^2+2n+1 = (n^2+an+b)(n^2+an+b)$.  Then, solve for $a$ and $b$.  If they are natural numbers, then that completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n^2+(n+1)^2+n^2(n+1)^2}&=\sqrt{(n^2+1)(n+1)^2+n^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(n^2+1+2n)(n+1)^2+n^2-2n(n+1)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(n+1)^4-2n(n+1)^2+n^2}\\
&=\sqrt{[(n+1)^2-n]^2}\\
&=(n+1)^2-n\\
&=n^2+n+1. 
\end{align*}
This is obviously a natural number for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.